# Почему когда захожу в базы данных через pgAdmin , ввожу пароль и все хорошо , а когда пытаюсь подключиться через терминал выдает ошибку

Tags: postgresql, psql, wsl

здесь приведен скриншот из WSL где у меня возникают проблемы с входом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на скриншоте вы пытаетесь от имени привилигированного пользователя (sudo) запустить сервер постгес (который вероятно уже запущен), что на самом деле вы хотите сделать? 

подключиться к работающему серверу постгрес из консоли это $ psql -h<host> -U<user> и т.п.

Comment: хочу подключиться по ssh к серверу

Comment: ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Давайте по частям:

1. Где установлен сервер POstgreSQL? На каком-то сервере или на вашей локальной машине в докер-контейнере?

2. Если на удаленной машине (сервере) то по ssh на этот сервер надо и заходить по ssh:
    $ ssh <логин_пользователя_сервера>@<IP_адрес_сервера>

3. Находясь в консоли той же машины (локальной или сервера) для подключения к серверу Постгреса нужно использовать консольный клиент - psql, как я писал в первом комментарии.

Comment: 4. Если Постгрес запущен внутри контейнера докер, то то покажите для начала, что выдает команда docker ps -a , так как подключаться надо по адресу контейнера и порту.

5. Как у вас настроено подключение в pgAdmin вы же можете посмотреть, если пишите, что через него вы заходите.